# Cannot access empty property - Sendgrid

Tags: php, ibm-cloud, sendgrid

Trying to use Sendgrid's API (running on bluemix) to send automated emails.

```
$sendgrid_username = 'XXXXXXXXX';
$sendgrid_password = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
$to                = $_SESSION['emailto'];
$from              = "XXXXXXXXXXX@XXXX.com";
$sendgrid = new SendGrid($sendgrid_username, $sendgrid_password, array("turn_off_ssl_verification" => true));
$email    = new SendGrid\Email();
$email->addTo($to)->
       setFrom($from)->
       setSubject('Password Reset')->
       setHtml("<b>A new password has been set for the user: %mailto%.<br> The new password is:                                                                            %pass%<br><br></b>")->
       addSubstitution("%mailto%", array($_SESSION['emailto']))->
       addSubstitution("%pass%", array($random_pass_clear))->
       addHeader('X-Sent-Using', 'SendGrid-API')->
       addHeader('X-Transport', 'web')->
$response = $sendgrid->send($email); //this is line 21
```

I've used the example code from Sendgrid and everything is working (email i being sent). I do however get 2 errors:

> PHP NOTICE: Undefined Variable response on line 21
>   PHP FATAL ERROR: Cannot access empty property on line 21

I've never encountered the second error before and I'm kind of confused as to what is going on... any idea's where I went wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`addHeader('X-Transport', 'web')->`   this excess `T_OBJECT_OPERATOR` (`->`) on line 20 is your bad guy.

It tries to use a `$response` variable in `$email` object on line 21.

Ignoring previous chaining, it essentially is trying to do this:

```
$email->$response = $sendgrid->send($email);
```

The sending is done, but it fails to put the method-result in the `$email->$response` variable (*Cannot access empty property*) because `$email->$response` is never defined (*Undefined Variable*)

Comment: Took me a while to understand your question but thank you! I've been staring at this for 3h completely lost...